# Prove a function is/is not differentiable at a point (using sequences)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to prove whether or not the following function is differentiable at the given points:

$$f(x) = |x - 2|\;\\at\;x = 2\;\\and\;\\at\;x = 1$$

I know that the function is differentiable at $x=1$, but I am not sure how to prove this.

I also know that the function is not differentiable at $x=2$, and I believe that I am supposed to come up with two different sequences that show as much.  However, I do not understand how to create sequences that will work.

Any tips to get me on the right track would be much appreciated!

Comment: For $2$: set $x_n=2+\frac{1}{n}$, $y_n=2-\frac{1}{n}$. you have $\frac{f(x_n)-f(2)}{x_n -2} = ? \to ?$, and $\frac{f(y_n)-f(2)}{y_n -2} = ? \to ?$

Comment: For $x = 1$ you see $x<2$ so $f(x) = |x - 2|= x - 2$ and $f'=1$.

Comment: @ClementC. First of all, thank you! I understand that with these sequences, $f'(x_n)$ will evaluate to $1$ and $f'(y_n)$ will evaluate to $-1$.  However, I do not understand the intuition here.  Why did you know to pick these sequences in particular?

Comment: Just graph the functions, and look at the slopes around $2$ (left and right)

Comment: @Hawleyluyah if you have a limit along two different subsequences evaluate to different things, what do you know about the limit of the sequence?

Comment: @qbert I think that's the key thing I'm missing here.  So if $x_n=2+1/n$ and $y_n=2−1/n$ are both subsequences, what would be the overarching sequence here?  I think something is lost on me in the transition from dealing with functions (such as $f(x)=|x-2|$) to sequences.

Comment: @Hawleyluyah I will try and elucidate in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Fact: A sequence has a limit if and only if any subsequence converges to the same limit.

An example of this fact in action:

What's a quick way to tell that a limit like 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin ( 1/x)
$$
doesn't exist? We can examine a pair of sequences converging to $0$ and find that our limit depends on choice of sequence.

$x_k=\frac{1}{2\pi k}$ and $y_k=\frac{1}{(2k+1/2)\pi}$.

Then, 
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sin(1/x_k)=0\ne \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sin(1/y_k)=1
$$
Thus, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(1/x)$ does not exist.

Try applying this to your problem with the suggested sequences: 
$$
x_n=2-1/n\rightarrow 2\\
y_n=2+1/n\rightarrow 2
$$
But 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(2)}{x_n-2}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|2-1/n-2|}{2-1/n-2}=\frac{|1/n|}{-1/n}=-1
$$
and by similar work, along the other sequence $y_n$ the limit is $1$. Thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: I think you made a computational error? For your particular choices of subsequences, shouldn't $f'(x_n)=-1$ and $f'(y_n)=1$?  Not too important to the intuition here but I just noticed this as I was trying to understand your answer.

Comment: @Hawleyluyah indeed you are correct! I will edit